# How to set the trigger only for the third column td,not all the td in a grid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to set the trigger only for the third column td,not all the td in a grid?
I had set all the td like this:

```
my.contextMenu({
        trigger: '#Grid  td ',
        rightButton: true,
        menu: '#testMenu',
        callback: ctxCallback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : `'#Grid tr>td:nth-child(3n)'`

```
my.contextMenu({
    trigger: '#Grid tr>td:nth-child(3n)',
    rightButton: true,
    menu: '#testMenu',
    callback: ctxCallback
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dieter Platner,When the trigger is used more than one column ,is it used like this?It seems wrong.
Try this one : '#Grid tr>td:nth-child(3n,4n,5n,6n)'

my.contextMenu({
    trigger: '#Grid tr>td:nth-child(3n,4n,5n,6n)',
    rightButton: true,
    menu: '#testMenu',
    callback: ctxCallback
});

Comment: In this case I would use the `:gt`-Selector: '#Grid tr>td:gt(3)'. Note that the :gt Selector uses 1-based indexing and the ':nth-child(3n)' uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: #Grid tr>td:gt(3) may contains columns column 1,2,3;but I  want  those which do not contains column 1,2,3

Comment: @flower you can write your own filter : `$.expr[':'].gtchild = function (elem) {return $(elem).parent().find("td").index($(elem)) > 2;};` and then you use it with `'#Grid td:gtchild'`. You can see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AB9js/1/

Comment: Hi, Samuel Caillerie,I want to get the td which value>0 and background is not red,How to change it ? "return $(elem).parent().find("td").index($(elem)) > 2 && $(elem).parent().find("td").text()>0" is not right